# Android with activities

Tags: android

I have problems with a menu systems that I made. four buttons the all work correctly but for one button that i have made it loads the wrong activity when I click on it, but when I click on the emulator's back button then it loads the correct activity and don't want this i want it to load the correct activity

This is the code that I have write for the menu 
the `check_view` loads the `question_view` where it should load the `check_view`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    appointment_image_view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.appointment_image_view);
    check_view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.check_view);
    questions_view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.questions_view);
    survey_view =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.survey_view);
    appointment_image_view.setOnClickListener(this);
    check_view.setOnClickListener(this);
    questions_view.setOnClickListener(this);
    survey_view.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View view){
 switch (view.getId())
 {
     case R.id.appointment_image_view:
         //  open
          Intent appointment_intent = new Intent(this,apppointmentactivity.class);
          this.startActivity(appointment_intent);
         break;
     case R.id.check_view:
         // open
         Intent  Health_intent1 = new Intent(this,HealthActivity.class);
         this.startActivity(Health_intent1);
     case R.id.questions_view:
         //open
         Intent Question_Intent = new Intent(this,QuestionsActivity.class);
         this.startActivity(Question_Intent);
         break;
     case R.id.survey_view:
         Intent Survery_intent = new Intent(this,SurveyActivity.class);
         this.startActivity(Survery_intent);
         break;

 }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your manifest file

Comment: Change: 
apppointmentactivity.class
To:
Apppointmentactivity.class
And check your manifest file.

Comment: Ok  thanks  I  kind a new to android app development is my first main app thanks for your help Rami

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking a `break;` after this:

```
case R.id.check_view:
         // open
         Intent  Health_intent1 = new Intent(this,HealthActivity.class);
         this.startActivity(Health_intent1);
```

Comment: Thanks qmar  i miss that break this had me stump thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `break;` at your `case R.id.check_view`.